# Laravel validator not works with custom request and added params

Tags: api, service, request, laravel-9

I have a custom request class and a service class in laravel to handle all requests in my app. Theese will handle api and web requests, that have two different controllers. But in web controller, when I try to add parameters to request on the fly, the validated() method does not recognoise them.

web controller:

```php
    public function index(ShopIndexRequest $request, ShopService $service)
    {
        $request->mergeIfMissing(['items' => 3]);
        //other tries to adding parameters
        //$request->request->add(['items' => 3]);
        //request()->request->add(['items' => 3]);
        //$request['items'] = 3;
        $shops = $service->getall($request);
        
        return view('shop.index', compact('shops'));
    }
```

Service class:

```php
    namespace App\Services;
    
    use App\Http\Requests\Shop\ShopIndexRequest;
    use App\Http\Resources\ShopResource;
    use App\Models\Shop;
    
    class ShopService{
    
        public function getAll(ShopIndexRequest $request)
        {
            $validated = $request->validated();
            $query = Shop::query();
    
            if(isset($validated['name'])){
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $validated['name'] . '%');
            }
    
            if(isset($validated['orderBy']) && isset($validated['orderDirection'])){
                $query->orderBy($validated['orderBy'], $validated['orderDirection']);
            }
    
            if(isset($validated['items'])){
                return ShopResource::collection($query->paginate($validated['items']));
            }
            else{
                return ShopResource::collection($query->paginate(config('app.defaultItemsPagination')));
            }
    
        }
    }
```

request class:

```php
    namespace App\Http\Requests\Shop;
    
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
    
    class ShopIndexRequest extends FormRequest
    {
        /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize()
        {
            return true;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array<string, mixed>
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'items' => 'integer|nullable',
                'name' => 'string|nullable',
                'orderBy' => 'string|nullable',
                'orderDirection' => 'string|nullable'
            ];
        }
    }
```

after calling validated() method in controller, it allways give me an empty array. however, in api controller it is working perfectly fine with postman, receving the parameters that I provide it in each request,

here is index method in api controller:

```php
    public function index(ShopIndexRequest $request, ShopService $service)
    {
        $shops = $service->getAll($request);
        return $shops;
    }
```

Why validated() method ignores data I added on the fly with all of theese methods? It is a way to acheive my goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the request. Then, use validated() as a mocked method of request in the test and set up the expectation for validated to return your desired value.

This mocks the service class:

$this->shopServiceMock=Mockery::mock(ShopService::class);
$this->app->instance(ShopService::class, $this->ShopServiceMock);

Now build a request that includes validated to return custom data

```
$request = $this->getMockBuilder(ShopIndexRequest::class)             - 
>setMethods(['validated'])->getMock(); 
$request->expects($this->once())->method('validated')         - 
>willReturn(true);
```

Now create an instance of the service class and inject the mock into that.

Comment: I don't understand you, don't know how do that.

Comment: this mocks the service class 

`$this->shopServiceMock=Mockery::mock(ShopService::class);
        $this->app->instance(ShopService::class, $this->ShopServiceMock);`

now build a request  that includes validated to return custom data

`$request = $this->getMockBuilder(ShopIndexRequest::class)
            ->setMethods(['validated'])
            ->getMock();`

        `$request->expects($this->once())
        ->method('validated')
        ->willReturn(true);
`
now create an instance of the service class and inject the mock into that instance.

Comment: I will check Mockery and try it. Thanks!